# Working with lists and slicing

Tags: python, list, function

This seems like an easy task and I honestly don't know what the problem is. I have a list such as [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] and such and I need to pick and index, lets say 3, and the output should look like [4,5,6,3,0,1,2] and here is my code

```
def cut_list(listA, index):
    return listA[index+1:] + listA[index] + listA[0:index]
```

Yet the listA[index] function isn't working properly and giving an error, however if I take out the other parts and only do "return listA[index]" it will output 3

Comment: "giving an error" -- What's the error?

Comment: `return listA[index+1:] + [listA[index]] + listA[0:index]`

Answer (score 3):

`listA[index]` is a scalar value which can't be concatenated with a list.  You're doing something akin to:

```
>>> 3 + []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Lists can only be concatenated with other lists, so the solution is to simply change `listA[index]` into a list with that as the only element.  e.g. `[listA[index]]`:

```
def cut_list(listA, index):
    return listA[index+1:] + [listA[index]] + listA[0:index]
```

---

To make it work for *most* sequence types, we can do a little clever slicing:

```
def cut_list(listA, index):
    return listA[index+1:] + listA[index:index+1] + listA[0:index]
```

This works because the slice `x[idx:idx+1]` *should* return a sequence of the same type as `x` that has only the `idx'th` element from `x`.

```
>>> cut_list(range(10), 3)
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 0, 1, 2]
>>> cut_list('foo3bar', 3)
'bar3foo'
>>> cut_list(tuple(range(10)), 3)
(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 0, 1, 2)
```

Comment: This would work but what I forgot to mention was that it has to work for just a string aswell, if I used ( ) instead of [ ], it works for string but not for list and vice versa

Comment: @HelloMellow -- I've updated with a solution that should work for most sequence types.

Comment: It works, thanks! But why is it that doing listA[index:index+1] doesn't result, in this case, the 3rd (as index=3) and 4th (index+1=3+1=4) term being printed out?

Comment: @HelloMellow -- Slicing returns up-to (but not including) the final index.  So, `lst[idx:idx]` will always give you an empty list.  It's the same reason why you need `listA[0:index]` rather than `listA[0:index-1]` in the last term.

Comment: Also note, we could do `listA[:index]` instead of `listA[0:index]` -- They do the same thing.

Comment: Ahh that makes so much sense, thanks for your help!!